# Read Email Form Data in C#

Tags: c#, exchange-server

I have created an Outlook Custom Form filled it in and sent it to my inbox.

Now, in my code i have;

```
        ExchangeService exchange = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);
        exchange.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        exchange.AutodiscoverUrl("firstname.lastname@companyname.com.au", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, -1, 0, 0);
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now.Add(ts);
        SearchFilter.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo filter = new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, date);

        if (exchange != null)
        {
            Folder inbox = Folder.Bind(exchange, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
            SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));
            ItemView view = new ItemView(1);
            FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = exchange.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, sf, view);

            foreach (Item item in findResults)
            {
                EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(exchange, item.Id);
                string messageBody = message.Body;
```

I can get the subject, the body etc. but how do I read the fields that are in the custom form?

So I have a field in the form called textbox1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to know the details of the MAPI property that your custom form  created in Outlook . You can easily find this out using a Mapi editor like MFCMapi or Outlook Spy. Once you know the GUID,Tag information you just need to define that and tell EWS to return the property to you eg most likely something like

```
ExtendedPropertyDefinition CustomProperty = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings, "CustomPropertyName", MapiPropertyType.String);
PropertySet ItemPropSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
ItemPropSet.Add(CustomProperty);
EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(exchange, item.Id,ItemPropSet);
```

see also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633697(v=exchg.80).aspx

Cheers
Glen